# React state gets updated but wont re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

This function in my main app.js component. Is called when I need to add certain properties to one of the objects in the state.

the function...
1 mirrors the state with [...books]
2. finds the object in the array, if it is not in the state it pushes it
3. adds the necessary properties
4. calls the server update and if the server response is positive...
5 updates the state with setBooks()

When the object happens to be in state and I only have to add properties to the object, the refresh happens.

But if the book object was not found in state and I am actually pushing the object to the state array...  it wont re-render. I need to push F5 on the browser  to see the object being rendered.

```
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);


  const changeShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    const updatedBooks = [...books];
    let found = updatedBooks.findIndex(element => book.id === element.id);
    if (found === -1) {
      updatedBooks.push(book);
      found = books.length - 1;
    }

    updatedBooks[found].shelf = shelf;
    updatedBooks[found].stamp = Date.now();


    BooksAPI.update(book, shelf).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data[shelf].includes(book.id)) setBooks(updatedBooks);
    });
  };
```

Comment: usually you have to do api calls in side effects. Please see useEffect hook to understand about side effects with react hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning this into an asynchronous function? If `BooksAPI.update()` returns a promise, you can wait for it to return with a response from the server.

```
 const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

 const async changeShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    const updatedBooks = [...books];
    let found = updatedBooks.findIndex(element => book.id === element.id);
    if (found === -1) {
      updatedBooks.push(book);
      found = books.length - 1;
    }

    updatedBooks[found].shelf = shelf;
    updatedBooks[found].stamp = Date.now();

    await BooksAPI.update(book, shelf).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data[shelf].includes(book.id)) setBooks(updatedBooks);
    });
  };
```